# PrimeNg table, issue editing checkbox

Tags: angular, primeng

In my angular 5 application I am using primeng "turbo" table and I have some issue when I try to edit a checkbox.
[primeNg - table](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table)

[image]

Like you see the checkbox is moving from the original position, is there a way to fix it?
This is the code:

```
   <p-cellEditor>
       <ng-template pTemplate="input">
           <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="rowData.ecommerceEnabled" (change)="loadPayForCheckbox($event, rowData._links.self.href)">
            </mat-checkbox>
       </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="output">
             <span class="ui-column-title">{{'paymenttype.table.headers.ecommerceenabled' | translate}} 
            </span>
             <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="rowData.ecommerceEnabled"></mat-checkbox>
        </ng-template>
    </p-cellEditor>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it on a StackBlitz please ?

Answer (score 1):

remove pEditableColumn in td tag

i.e. replace  instead of

it works for me